# Indexing nested JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, indexing

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to index in JSON.

Here is an example JSON that is similar to what I am working with:

```
 {
    "Customers": [
        {
          "FieldOne": 0,
          "FieldTwo": {
               "Blah": "233223",
               "Target": "GOAL"
           }
         }
       ]
    }
```

How would I go about getting the target property?

I've tried this:

```
var unparsed = JSON.stringify(body)
var data = JSON.parse(unparsed)
var tgt = data.Customers.FieldTwo.Target
```

But it doesn't work and tells me that it is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data.Customers` is an array containing the customer object, you'll need to access `data.Customers[0].FieldTwo.Target` instead of `data.Customers.FieldTwo.Target`. Example:

```
var tgt = data.Customers[0].FieldTwo.Target
```

Notice that `body` is JSON object, **not** a string in this code sample:

```js
var body = 
{
    "Customers": [{
        "FieldOne": 0,
        "FieldTwo": {
            "Blah": "233223",
            "Target": "GOAL"
        }
    }]
}
;

var unparsed = JSON.stringify(body);
var data = JSON.parse(unparsed);
var tgt = data.Customers[0].FieldTwo.Target;
document.write(tgt);
```

But here `body` is a string, so there is no need to stringify it:

```js
var b = 
`{
    "Customers": [{
        "FieldOne": 0,
        "FieldTwo": {
            "Blah": "233223",
            "Target": "GOAL"
        }
    }]
}`
;

// var unparsed = JSON.stringify(b);  <-- no need to stringify
var data = JSON.parse(b);
var tgt = data.Customers[0].FieldTwo.Target;
document.write(tgt);
```

Comment: When Indexing array elements in JSON, do the indexes refer to anything enclosed by '{ }' ? And then the different properties within braces are then retrieved by the "." ?

Comment: The problem is that It says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: If you have an array like this: `"myarray": [ {"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"} ]`, `myarray[0]` will refer to `{"name": "foo"}` and `myarray[1]` will refer to `{"name": "bar"}`. I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Why would I be getting undefined errors? Could it be because "Customers" isn't the only field in my JSON code?

Comment: Is `body` a javascript object or a JSON string? If it is a string then you'll need to replace line 1 and 2 with `data = JSON.parse(body)`.